# MongoDB: convert string timestamp to Int64

Tags: mongodb

I have the strings in format:

> { "Duration": "6.10:26:27.2587880" },
> { "Duration": "05:33:01.3882716" },
> { "Duration": "00:00:22.1100191" }

How to convert them to Int64 for MongoDB Compass migration script?

In C# entity it has TimeSpan type, but I forgot to add

> [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]

and MongoDB saved it as a string.

Comment: ChatGPT already helped me. Question closed.